# Angular 4 display custom RxJS Subject in template

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a custom RxJS Subject that represents the distance in meters over time (making a navigation app). It gets updated over time in different places. A simplified version is:

**Inside a service**

```
this.distance$ = new Subject();

// After some event
this.distance$.next(1234)

// After another event
this.distance$.next(1240);

getDistance() {
    return this.distance$;
}
```

The above seems to work. When I write the following code in my component I do get an update in the console with the new value whenever it changes.

```
this.myService.getDistance().subscribe(distance => console.log(distance));
```

But when I try to show it in my component template it never updates beyond the first value.

**My component**

```
this.distance$ = this.myService.getDistance();
```

**My template**

```
<p>{{distance$ | async}}</p>
```

The displayed value is always equal to the first emitted distance. It never gets updated.

In another attempt I wrote this in my component which never showed any results at all:

```
this.routeBuilderService.getDistance().subscribe(distance => this.distance = distance);
```

And then the template just contained {{distance}}.

Comment: This should work. Please reproduce it https://plnkr.co/edit/L2gX2jkThR9fSShNDriI?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the Plunkr. My entire code is here: https://github.com/ErikNijland/routebuilder/tree/master/src/app/components/route and https://github.com/ErikNijland/routebuilder/tree/master/src/app/services/route-builder.

Could it be related to calling next inside a async function? Also the click events aren't Angular event but from Google Maps.

I'll try to replicate it myself in Plunkr as well.

Comment: When you are working with Google Maps you can run code outside angular zone after that angular won't run change detection cycle

Comment: Does that mean that Angular's template change detection is not in sync with RxJS events/updates? That is strange since I tried a Plunkr with setInterval (native, non-Angular) and that does work: https://plnkr.co/edit/zVT6goEgZBfzepz9Vyc2?p=preview

Comment: Angular doesn't update template if code is executed outside angular zone. How can i reproduce the issue in your app?

Comment: Thanks can confirm this now. When doing another unrelated Angular click event it updates the value all of the sudden. Next issue is ofcourse how to solve it but that's unrelated to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to a getter so it re-executes:

```
get distance$() {return this.myService.getDistance();}
```

You could take this a step further and get rid of the subject entirely. Just define a simple property in the service that is shared. Then the getter approach should work.

I have an example here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/